# Text in merged Table

Tags: tables

I don't know why my text in the top of merged column will always be duplicated.
 `\textbf{A}` in line 6 show in the table will be AA which I cannot figure out why.

Thank you for help.

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
    \subfloat[$A\land B$ (AND)]{\label{fig:fAndOp}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hhline {~~|---}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ \textbf{A}} \tabularnewline
            \hhline {~~|---}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\Large$ \land  $  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{0} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{1} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{N}\tabularnewline
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{0} & 0 & 0 & N\tabularnewline
            \hhline {|~|----}
             \textbf{B}& \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{1} & 0 & 1 & N\tabularnewline
            \hhline {|~|----}
             & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{N} & N & N & N\tabularnewline
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\caption{Primitive functions in three-value logic }
\label{fig:fOperators}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I'm getting [the desired output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SAdXt.png). You must be doing something else as well that is not included here. Do you receive any errors/warnings in the `.log`? Note that you have spurious spaces in your input that is causing some misalignment.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me. You need to make a full MWE as below to localize the issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig,hhline,xcolor,colortbl,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\subfloat[$A\land B$ (AND)]{\label{fig:fAndOp}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hhline {~~|---}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{A}} \tabularnewline
        \hhline {~~|---}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\Large$ \land  $  & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{0} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{1} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{N}\tabularnewline
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}\textbf{0} & 0 & 0 & N\tabularnewline
        \hhline {|~|----}
         \textbf{B}& \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{1} & 0 & 1 & N\tabularnewline
        \hhline {|~|----}
         & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9} \textbf{N} & N & N & N\tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\caption{Primitive functions in three-value logic }
\label{fig:fOperators}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]